# regex: getting only a range of matches

Tags: regex

My Regex: https://regex101.com/r/IKN80n/3

What I'm trying to do is get only a range of those matches, from month_3 to month_11, inclusive.

I've tried using the {3,11} and some iterations of it, but no go. Is it possible to not get all 12 matches but only the range I need?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it is by using Negative Lookahead, this could be useful if the list that you try to exclude is shorter than the list that you try to include:

```
(?!month_(01|02|12))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/QIM9cl/1/

Version 2: https://regex101.com/r/QIM9cl/2/

Comment: Thanks, that's a little more elegant that what I figured out and also a good example for others. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://regex101.com/r/IKN80n/4

Is what I came up with. I suppose it works, not sure how elegant it is, but working.